# Can the administrator of a remote Citrix system see the files or desktop of a client machine running Citrix client software?

Tags: privacy, citrix, citrix-receiver

I work with more than one company and need to know if the administrators of a remote Citrix system are able to see anything on my local desktop, or if they are able open files on my local hard-drive. Is the remote user's privacy 100% ensured when remoting into a Citrix server? Do they have any way to see my desktop or printer queue or access my hard drives?   I need to be able to say to Company B that there's absolutely no way for Company A to access data that Company B may have shared with me.